# What is the difference between bicubic and cubic?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

I am trying to do image interpolation in my code. Recently I heard an image interpolation method called "bicubic". Does it has any relationship with "cubic"? If yes, what is the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49100/how-does-nearest-neighbour-bilinear-and-cubic-interpolation-work-in-images https://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic

Answer (score 6):

"Bicubic" is simply cubic interpolation applied in two dimensions.

A similar term is "bilinear", which is linear interpolation in two dimensions. "trilinear" is linear interpolation in 3D. I have not yet seen the term "tricubic". :)

In general, any interpolation scheme can be implemented using a 1D interpolation algorithm. One first interpolates, for example, the rows of the image. In the result, one interpolates the columns. In a 3D image one then would interpolate also along the 3rd dimension.

Thus, if you know how 1D cubic interpolation works, you can also derive how 2D or 3D cubic interpolation works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question: I read from book that cubic interpolation uses two points each time. Is bicubic interpolation the same? I readed from wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) that bicubic uses 16 pixels, why so much pixels?

Comment: @zhuofeng Go here and hover your mouse over the words *"Bicubic Interpolation"* to see answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Image_processing

Comment: @zhuofeng: Mark is right, the Wikipedia page has a good graphic that makes all of this clear. Cubic interpolation uses 4 points. If you do that in 2D you end up using 16 points in a 4x4 grid for each output pixel.

Comment: You can use (and I have done in the past) the technique that you describe. However it only applies to data that that is on some sort of grid. The grid need neither be regular nor complete. If you want to interpolate on scattered data then you need to consider something like Shepard's method. As the question is tagged #image-processing it's probably safe to assume a regular grid.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: Good comment. Indeed this method of combining 1D interpolation to obtain higher-dimensional interpolation requires a grid. Though I have not heard the term "bicubic" being applied in scattered data situations.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it.